# why I am getting store is undefined error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

Hope you are doing great. Here, I am trying to store my fetched data into my redux store and then want to use those data on my components but suddenly I am getting an error which is,[image: Store is Undefined].
The code of my store is,

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import userReducer from "../features/userSlice";

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userReducer,
  },
});
```

The code of my userSlice is,

```
const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    posts: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    setPosts: (state, action) => {
      state.posts = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { setPosts } = userSlice.actions;
export const selectPosts = (state) => state.user.posts;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

And the component where i am trying to get access the stored data is,

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import axios from "axios";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import img from "../assets/index.jpeg";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { setPosts, selectPosts } from "../redux/features/userSlice";
function Posts() {
  //const [state, setState] = useState([]);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const posts = useSelector(selectPosts);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then((response) => {
        //setState(response);
        console.log("fetched");
        dispatch(setPosts(response));
      })
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="Posts">
      <div>
        <Container>
          <Row>
            {console.log(posts)}
            {/* {!posts &&
              posts.data.map((post) => (
                <Col
                  xs={3}
                  style={{
                    margin: "15px",
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    border: "1px black solid",
                  }}
                >
                  <div className="post__data">
                    <img alt="image" src={img} />
                    {post.title}
                    <Link to={"/post/" + post.id}>See more</Link>
                  </div>
                </Col>
              ))} */}
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Posts;
```

I will be glad if I get a solution to this weird problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you provided store to your react app?

Comment: Yeah.! but still the problem is same.

Comment: it's not clear with just this information what is the problem, try to add more info, like complete `index.js` file, complete store file, complete slice file

Answer (score 0):

Simply import configureStore:
`import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'`

Comment: imported it. still the problem remains the same.

Comment: Where do you provide your component tree with with redux provider? Add the necessary information

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I added the store in the wrong place that's why I got the error. The problem has been solved.